# What is the meaning of porcupine that Maria Hill drew when recruiting Grant Ward in Marvel Agents of SHIELD

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In Agents of SHIELD Season 1 Episode 1, Agent Maria Hill recruits Agent Grant Ward into a mobile command unit. In Ward's evaluation, she drew a poop/porcupine under people skills. What did that mean?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question, please add a comment why. It will help me.

Comment: I think it is because for some people the meaning just feels very obvious. But it apparently is not :)

Comment: Don't worry about getting close votes.  There are users on this site that have zero clue about how the site works, yet they still seem to feel the need to put close votes on perfectly acceptable questions.  Your question is completely fine.  It's all good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this was supposed to reflect his personality, as 'prickly' and generally a displeasure to work with.

As mentioned in the [MCU Fandom](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Grant_Ward#Agent_of_S.H.I.E.L.D.):

> "Deputy Director Maria Hill gave Ward top marks in combat and the highest espionage rating since Natasha Romanoff, giving him low marks only in his people skills."